# Need Advice for ASP.NET Form Builder

Tags: asp.net, formbuilder

I would like learn and create customizable registration form , user can edit and build all sorts of forms with different element something like Google Docs online form , i want to learn how to develop simple form like that using .NET technology, can anyone kindly advice me what is the best approach and are there any tutorial available to follow?

~thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's the whole **[bunch of tutorials](http://www.asp.net/learn).** This is a great place of asp.net learners.

**http://www.asp.net/learn/**

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to understand, how much you know already.
If you have just started - [this](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-562&locale=en-us) might be useful.